# Unknown Error Message When Creating my first project in googles developer console

Tags: google-api, developer-console

I am trying to get a google maps API Key so that I can use google maps on my website. When attempting to create my first ever project in the developer console I get the error message attached. I cannot create a project in the developer console to obtain an API Key.

I've tried updated my billing information but still no luck. Any ideas?

[image: Unknown error message]

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually having the same issue. I did a little troubleshooting and this is the error I found.

> script:https://console.developers.google.com/support/overview?creatingProject=true
>   error:[$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.12-local+sha.7f65bbb8d/$resource/badcfg?p0=ackFailed&p1=object&p2=array&p3=POST&p4=%2Fm%2Foperations%2FackFailed
>   line:Not available

I'm not sure but it looks like a bad config or something on google's end.